# WCF End point not found error from self-hosted service

Tags: c#, wcf, endpoint, self-hosting, endpointnotfoundexception

i´m getting an "End point not found" when calling a WCF service. It is a Self-hosted service in a console app.

Here is my code:

**IService.cs**

```
namespace ClassLibrary
{
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    string GetMessage(string inputMessage);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke]
    string PostMessage(string inputMessage);
}
```

}

**Service.cs**

```
namespace ClassLibrary
{
public class Service : IService
{
    public string GetMessage(string inputMessage)
    {
        return "En GetMessage llega " + inputMessage;
    }

    public string PostMessage(string inputMessage)
    {
        return "En PostMessage llega " + inputMessage;
    }
}
```

}

**And the console app:**

```
namespace ConsoleHost
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri("http://localhost:8000"));
        ServiceEndpoint ep = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), new WebHttpBinding(), "");
        ServiceDebugBehavior db = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
        db.HttpHelpPageEnabled = false;

        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Service is up and running");
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to quit ");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

}

There is no config file because it is all in the code.

And the call to the service:

```
http://localhost:8000/
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: It may be helpful to share some config too: WCF errors are notoriously configuration dependent.

Comment: Can you share client code too? Do you use same endpoint configuration on the client (WebHttpBinding)?

Comment: are you sure your console is running ?! sometimes...

Comment: Why are you creating a `ServiceEndpoint ep` and not doing anything with it? It's an unused variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things. Services hosted with `WebServiceHost` do not publish metadata, so don't bother trying to get a WSDL with just the service name.

Because its WebGet, you are calling the Get method by default when you enter the service name, so you should supply any needed parameters in the URL. However, this won't work until you declare the form of the request in the contract. Do this by modifying the the WebGet line as follows:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "{inputMessage}")]
```

Yes, the attribute property must match the formal parameter of the GetMessage() operation, in this case "inputMessage"

With the service running, enter the following URL into a browser to verify the service works:

```
http://localhost:8000/hello
```

You should get something like:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
En GetMessage llega hello</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this for you [WCF REST Self-Hosted 400 Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705744/wcf-rest-self-hosted-400-bad-request?rq=1)
Effectively you are developping a REST Service, and for this there are two things to know:
1- You don't need to add EndPoint and Behaviors when using WebServiceHost
2- Rest Services don't have wsdl exposed, so you can't add a service refenrence from VS for example.